# How to config gRPC message size in Hyperledger Fabric 2.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, grpc, grpc-java

I got an error when trying to invoke base64 string to smart contract

```
An error occurred on the chaincode stream. Shutting down the chaincode stream.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: gRPC message exceeds maximum size 4194304: 12366828
```

How can I fix this error?

I try to add these line in my connection_profile.json, but it's still not working

```
 "peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://192.168.117.141:7051",
        "eventUrl": "grpcs://192.168.117.141:7053",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com",
            "hostnameOverride": "peer0.org1.example.com",
            "grpc.max_receive_message_length": -1,
            "grpc.max_send_message_length": -1
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----######3-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
        }
    },
```

Trying this still not working too.

```
    Properties peerProperties = new Properties();
    peerProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.maxInboundMessageSize", 90000000);
    peerProperties.put("grpc.max_send_message_length", -1);
    peerProperties.put("grpc.max_receive_message_length", -1);

    Gateway.Builder gateWaybuilder = Gateway.createBuilder();

    Path walletPath = getWalletPath(config);
    Path connectionProfile = getConnectionProfile(config);

    Wallet wallet = Wallet.createFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
    Gateway.Builder identity = gateWaybuilder.identity(wallet, config.getUserName());
    identity.networkConfig(connectionProfile).discovery(false).connect();
```

Comment: have you been able to solve this problem?